# cloud SQL proxy initialization actions while creating Dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, cloud-sql-proxy

I am executing the attached script, `cloud-sql-proxy.sh`, as part of initialization actions while creating Dataproc cluster; it fails with the below error:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Attached `cloud-sql-proxy.sh` script along with the error logs.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?